# Chatterbot library and Heroku deployment

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I created my first chatbot with Chatterbot library. Now I want to deploy it through Heroku, but this is impossible.

My chatbot is composed of some files (py, csv, yml, json, txt). This is the structure:

botusers (csv file)
Magghy (py file)
magghybot (py file)
Procfile
Requirements (txt file)
telegramtoken (txt file)
conversation.yml (in folder named lang)
math_words.json (in folder named lang)
nltk (txt file)
runtime (txt file)

I created a "Procfile" (worker: python magghybot.py) and "Requirements.txt"

Then I deployed my project on Heroku and there isn't problem. But when I tried to start a conversation with my bot, it doesn't answer me.

When I write on Terminal heroic logs, there aren't problem, but only this strings:

```html
2017-10-18T10:16:08.079891+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command python magghybot.py
2017-10-18T10:16:08.745016+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-10-18T10:16:10.087633+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-10-18T10:16:10.098959+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-10-18T10:16:10.100468+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-10-18T10:16:14.445838+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command python magghybot.py
2017-10-18T10:16:14.982759+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-10-18T10:16:15.767656+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-10-18T10:16:15.782460+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

It seems there is a problem with my files py.

My magghybot.py has this code:

```html
import sys
from inspect import getsourcefile
from os.path import abspath
from chatterbot import ChatBot

class MagghyBot(object):
    
    def __init__(self, lang = "english"):
        self.language = lang
        self.chatbot = ChatBot(
            'MagghyBot',
            logic_adapters=[
            "chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
            "chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
            "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"
            ],
            #input_adapter="chatterbot.input.VariableInputTypeAdapter",
            #output_adapter="chatterbot.output.OutputAdapter"
            trainer='chatterbot.trainers.ChatterBotCorpusTrainer'
        ) 
        self.instdir = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/chatterbot_corpus/data" + self.language + "/"
        self.localdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) + "/lang/" + self.language + "/chatcorpus/"

    def train(self):
        if self.checkdirnotempty(self.localdir):
            print(self.localdir)
            self.chatbot.train(
                self.localdir
            )
        elif self.checkdirnotempty(self.instdir):
            print(self.instdir)
            self.chatbot.train(
                self.instdir
            )
        else:
            print("Using standard english corpus")
            self.chatbot.train("chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings")
    
    def reply(self, phrase = ""):
        # Get a response to an input statement
        response = self.chatbot.get_response(phrase)
        return response
    
    def checkdirnotempty(self, folder = ""):
        check = False
        if os.path.isdir(folder):
            entities = os.listdir(folder)
            for entity in entities:
                if os.path.isfile(folder + entity):
                    check = True
                    break
        return check
```

My Magghy.py has this code:

```html
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from magghybot import MagghyBot

telegramtoken = '' #telegram bot token from BotFather
checkuserid = 394287240 #enable users whitelist, so only certain people can talk with this bot
usersfile = 'botusers' #the file where we store the list of users who can talk with bot
attemptsfile = '/tmp/attempts.log' #the file where we log denied accesses
active = 1 #if set to 0 the bot will stop

language = "italiano"

chatter = MagghyBot(language)
chatter.train()

if telegramtoken == '' and os.path.isfile("telegramtoken.txt"):
    text_file = open("telegramtoken.txt", "r")
    telegramtoken = text_file.read().replace("\n", "")
    text_file.close()

print("Connecting to Telegram...")
bot = telepot.Bot(telegramtoken)
print(bot.getMe())



    
def listusers():
    if not os.path.isfile(usersfile):
        return ''
    text_file = open(usersfile, "r")
    lines = text_file.read().split(',')
    text_file.close()
    del lines[-1] #remove last element since it is blank
    return lines

def adduser(name):
    csv = ""
    users = listusers()
    if users != "":
        for usr in users:
            csv = csv+usr+","
    csv = csv+name+","
    text_file = open(usersfile, "w")
    text_file.write(csv)
    text_file.close()
    
def deluser(name):
    csv = ""
    users = listusers()
    if users != "":
        for usr in users:
            if usr != name:
                csv = csv+usr+","
    text_file = open(usersfile, "w")
    text_file.write(csv)
    text_file.close()

def handle(msg):
    global bot
    global chatter
    global language
    
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    sender = msg['from']['id']

    users = listusers()


    if checkuserid == 1:
        verified = 0
        if users != "":
            for usr in users:
                if str(sender) == usr:
                    verified = 1
        if verified == 0:
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "I don't talk with strangers, dear "+str(sender))
            #write this user in the list of attempted accesses
            if attemptsfile != '':
                lines = ''
                if os.path.isfile(attemptsfile):
                    text_file = open(attemptsfile, "r")
                    lines = text_file.read()
                    text_file.close()
                lines = lines + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " --- UserdID: " + str(sender) + " DENIED \n"
                text_file = open(attemptsfile, "w")
                text_file.write(lines)
                text_file.close()
            return
    
    command = ''
    
        
    try:
        if msg['text'] != '':
            command = msg['text']
            print('Got command: ' + command)
    except:
        print("No text in this message")
        

    if command == '/time':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    elif '/adduser' in command:
        if len(command.split(' ')) > 1:
            usrname = command.split(' ')[1]
            adduser(usrname)
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "User "+usrname+" added")
    elif '/deluser' in command:
        if len(command.split(' ')) > 1:
            usrname = command.split(' ')[1]
            deluser(usrname)
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "User "+usrname+" deleted")
    elif command == '/help':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "/adduser /deluser /time /exit")
    elif command == '/exit':
        global active
        active = False
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "The bot will shutdown in 10 seconds")
    elif command != '':
        answer = chatter.reply(command)
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(answer))



bot.message_loop(handle)
print('I am listening ...')

while active:
    time.sleep(10)
print("Exiting")
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using database on Heroku and not regular files to store data. Heroku is a cloud hosting and every launch could be made on different machines. That imposes some limitations on disk usage.

Here’s my experimental project - Django Telegram chatbot prepared for Heroku deployment

https://github.com/lisitsky/dj-tg-alpha-bot

Feeel free to ask questions on it and it’s work logics.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so my problem caused by the local paths (self.instdir and self.localdir)? In positive case, I have to change entire structure, using Django. :(

Comment: Django is not the only way to build a Bot. I’ve used because it gives some useful things like admin panel

Comment: Try to keep data in database. Python has nice libraries like `psycopg2`.

Comment: I had a confirm about the problem through the Heorku logs:                                      

 State changed from up to crashed
/app/lang/italiano/chatcorpus/
File "Magghy.py", line 27, in <module>
chatter.train()
File "/app/magghybot.py", line 37, in train
self.localdir
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chatterbot/trainers.py", line 137, in train
Response(previous_statement_text)